# How to imply ‘1-ness’ properly?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, adjective

My question is about the words *einzig* ‘only, unique’, *ein* ‘a, one’, *einzeln* ‘single’, *allein* ‘alone, only’, *ledig* ‘single’ and *einig* ‘united’.

I’m always confused to use the words in a context. Do they have completely different usage or are they interchangeable from a specific point? And are there some other words that imply ‘a, single, one, unique’, except the ones I listed?

If these words refer to ‘one’, why do they have different usages?

Comment: That's a bit broad. Try [this dictionary](http://www.dict.cc/?s=einzig), and see if there's still some unclarities left.

Comment: @Crissov, thanks for editing and now it reflects my real question ;-)

Answer (score 5):

There are differences:

- einzige = there is only one
- eine = one (but **not** the only one — sometimes used as “any”)
- einzelne = individual ones (can you hand over the nails to me one by
  one?)
- allein = alone, sometimes in the sense of ‘only’
- ledig = single, unmarried

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Ingmar, I didn't notice I had fscked the format.

Answer (score 3):

The same goes for english, really! Let's try and translate some english words which imply one-ness into german and shower you with examples, to supplement Craig's answer.

**one**

- eins (number one -> Nummer eins)
- einer/eine/eines (one of them -> einer von ihnen)
- ein (one house -> ein Haus)

**a**

- ein (a house -> ein Haus)

**single**

- einzig (not a single word -> kein einziges Wort)
- ledig (relationship status)

**sole**

- einzig (the sole purpose -> der einzige Grund)
- einzeln, einzig (one sole tree -> ein einzelner Baum)
- ledig (negative connotations; one sole tree was left -> ein lediger Baum blieb übrig) - that might be a regional thing though (Lower Austria), I've never heard a german say that
- alleinig (the sole ruler -> der alleinige Herrscher)

**solely**

- lediglich (much more common than "ledig")
- ausschließlich (this message is directed solely towards you -> Diese Nachricht ist ausschließlich für dich bestimmt)
- einzig
- nur

**alone** (**lone**, **lonely**)

- *ein*sam (lone wolf -> einsamer Wolf, "Einzelgänger"; I was lonely -> ich war einsam)
- allein(ig) (lone parent -> Alleinerzieher; I was alone -> ich war allein)

**any**

- irgendein (Give me any -> Gib mir irgendeines)
- kein (I don't watch any sports -> Ich schaue keinen Sport)

**anything**

- irgendetwas (Give me anything -> Gib mir irgendetwas)
- alles (I love you more than anything -> Ich liebe dich mehr als alles andere)

**mere**

- bloß (a mere shadow of his former self -> ein bloßer Schatten seiner selbst)
- schier (mere greed -> schiere Gier)
- nur

**only**

- einzig
- nur (only for you -> nur für dich)
- bloß (it was only a one-night-stand -> es war bloß ein One-night-stand)

Answer (score 1):

Some further words of that group:

- *einig* - *united* in thought (*thinking* alike, in agreement). *Darüber sind wir uns einig*.
- *einigen* - *come to an agreement*
- *geeint* - *united*
- *vereinen* - *to unite*, from that *vereint*, *Vereinte Nationen*(UN) or *Nach langer Trennung waren sie wieder vereint.*(got back together). can be a euphemism for sex
- *vereinigen* - *to unify/unite*, from that *vereinigt*. This implies a strong union. *Vereinigte Staaten*(USA), *Wiedervereinigung*(Reunification), can be a euphemism for sex
- *einzigartig* - *unique*, often exchangeable with *einzig*. However, *einzigartig* is more an *extremely special*, while *einzig* means that there really is just/only this one object, person or opportunity. Compare *a unique opportunity*(*eine einzigartige Gelegenheite*) to *the only opportunity*(*die einzige Gelegenheit*)
- *allein*, *einsam* - *alone*, *lonely*. *allein* can mein *only* in some cases (as alone in English)
- *einzeln* - *indivually (from a group)* or a *single* one. Taking nails one at a time from a heap = *Die Nägel einzeln von einem Haufen nehmen*. *Ein einzelner Nagel steckt in der Wand*. Rarely applicable to persons (*Ein einzelner Mann stellte sich der Meute entgegen.* or *Ein Mann stellte sich der Meute allein entgegen*. But **not** *Ich bin einzeln.* That would need *einsam* or *allein* (or *ledig* if not lonely, but merely unmarried.)

They really have slightly differing meaning, regarding which kind or degree of one-ness or uniqueness is expressed. In most cases, their English cognates are restricted in a similar manner, however.

*ein* of course also is the indefinite article *a/an* in many cases, an no special one-ness is implied.

Comment: Very nice answers,i think i'll bookmark them